# c# Amazon Api request fail

Tags: c#, winforms, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to create a HTTP url request to get Amazon items by its ASIN Array. I'm using the same code in my Objective-c code for the same reason and it's work perfectly.

But i'm getting this messeage everytime i try to access the url in my chrome:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

This is the code i'm using:

```
private void GetFinalUrlForAsinArray(ArrayList asinArr)
{
    String timeStamp = GetTimeStamp();

    String amazonAPIUrl = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?";

    ArrayList param = new ArrayList();
    param.Add("AWSAccessKeyId=myawsaccesskeyid");

    param.Add("AssociateTag=myassociatetag");

    param.Add("IdType=ASIN");
    param.Add(string.Join(",", asinArr.ToArray()));
    param.Add("Operation=ItemLookup");
    param.Add("ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes,Offers");
    param.Add("Service=AWSECommerceService");
    param.Add(String.Format("Timestamp={0}", timeStamp));

    amazonAPIUrl += string.Join("&", param.ToArray());

    string queryString = new System.Uri(amazonAPIUrl).Query;
    var queryDictionary = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);

    ArrayList queryItemsNew = new ArrayList();
    foreach (var query in queryDictionary)
    {
        String name = HttpUtility.UrlEncode((string)query);
        String value = HttpUtility.UrlEncode((string)queryDictionary.Get((string)query));
        queryItemsNew.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", name,value));
    }

    String path = string.Join("&", queryItemsNew.ToArray());

    String finalPath = String.Format("GET\nwebservices.amazon.com\n/onca/xml\n{0}",path);

    string signature = HmacSha256Digest(finalPath);

    String finalUrl = String.Format("http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?{0}&Signature={1}", path, signature);
}

private String GetTimeStamp()
{
    DateTime d = DateTime.UtcNow;
    String str = d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss''Z''");

    return str;
}

private static string HmacSha256Digest(string message)
{
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(encoding.GetBytes(mysecret));
    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(message)));
    String sigEncoded = Uri.EscapeDataString(signature);
    return sigEncoded;
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList` was deprecated when .NET 2.0 was. You should either use `string[]` or `List<string>`

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the AWS SDK for .NET? https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having had a look at the API documentation it looks like you've missed the ItemId key here:

```
param.Add(string.Join(",", asinArr.ToArray()));
```

I'm guessing you meant it to be:

```
param.Add("ItemId=" + string.Join(",", asinArr.ToArray()));
```

It otherwise looks to comply with the spec, the only other thing I noted was the example had the URL encoding as uppercase i.e. %3A rather than the C# default %3a.